# python module already installed elsewhere

Tags: python, module, pip, anaconda, python-idle

Im trying to use the pyperclip module in the idle python editor. When I try to import I get an error saying:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       import pyperclip
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'

When I try to pip install pyperclip in terminal, I get the following:

> Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.7.0)

Im brand new to learning python and developing in general, so sorry if this is an easy solution or covered elsewhere that I could not figure out how to find. Im still learning how to most effectively use python so I'm not sure which editor or system I prefer yet. Is there a way to be able to use the pyperclip module in idle without deleting it from anaconda, or removing anaconda entirely?

Im running python 3.7.2 on a Macbook with macOS Mojave 10.14.3.

Thanks!

Comment: IDLE is presumably not running in your Anaconda env.

Comment: in your code `print(sys.executable)` and compare with command output of `which pip`

Comment: When I  `print(sys.executable)` i get `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7` but when I use `which pip` in terminal I get `/anaconda3/bin/pip`. How can I install, copy, or move the pyperclip module to be able to use pyperclip in idle?

Comment: `cd` to 3.7 dir, then find the **pip**, run **it** to install library. you should learn something called `virtual environment`, which your ide created(and you have option to tell it not to)

Comment: In terminal when I `cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7`

then

`pip install pyperclip` 

I still get 

`Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in /Anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.7.0)`.

When I try `pip install --ignore-installed pyperclip` in the same location, I see
`Collecting pyperclip
Installing collected packages: pyperclip
Successfully installed pyperclip-1.7.0`

Then when I check `ls /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7` 

I do not see pyperclip in the list of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terminal, the following

```
$ python3 -m pip install pyperclip
```

or similar should install pyperclip or other modules to the python3 installation, where it can be found when you run IDLE with

```
$ python3 -m idlelib
```

I expect the same to be true when you start IDLE from the icon or python launcher, but I don't know what changes Anaconda makes to your system.